# Formula for Multiple of $23$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For any non-negative integer, why is $$(3^n) \cdot (2^{3n})-1$$ always a multiple of $23$?  I'm thinking of pulling out the $n$ and doing something with mod.

Comment: I've edited your post to include MathJax. Please verify that it says what you intended.

Comment: "I'm thinking of pullout the $n$." Good. Do that. Did you do it? What did you get? Rather than telling us what you're thinking of doing and then asking us for an answer, you should first actually do what you were thinking of doing, since it's not at all hard!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$3^n2^{3n}-1=24^n-1$

Now, Since $24\equiv 1\pmod {23}\implies 24^n\equiv ?\pmod{23}$

Answer (score 2):

$$(3^n) \cdot (2^{3n})-1=(3\cdot 2^3)^n-1=24^n-1^n=(24-1)\cdot (24^{n-1}+..+1^{n-1})$$

Answer (score 1):

This is $24^n - 1$ and you have
$$ z^n - 1 = (z-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} z^k.$$